# enviar input y devolverlo por pantalla

Tags: javascript, html, css

lo que quiero es que al tocar enter me muestre el input en pantalla, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let input = document.querySelector('#myInput');
    
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let resultado = input.value;
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
          article.innerHTML = `<h1>${resultado}</h1>`
      }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu estás haciendo un `innerHTML` a la variable `article`, pero nunca lo estás definiendo. Me imagino que esta variable será un elemento de tu HTML, por la cual debes capturarlo al igual que tu `input`:

```
let article = document.querySelector('#article');
```

Además, no le veo sentido el `e.preventDefault()`, ya que con esto evitas el evento por defecto del `keydown` en tu input, es decir, evitas que se procesen las pulsaciones de teclas en el evento `keydown`, lo cual impide que puedas escribir en el campo de entrada:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let input = document.querySelector('#myInput');
  let article = document.querySelector('#article');

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let resultado = input.value;
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      article.innerHTML = `<h1>${resultado}</h1>`
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<div id="article"></div>
```

Solo debes quitarlo y funcionaría correctamente.

---

#### Ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let input = document.querySelector('#myInput');
  let article = document.querySelector('#article');

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    let resultado = input.value;
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      article.innerHTML = `<h1>${resultado}</h1>`
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<div id="article"></div>
```